# Login to Paytm login page using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

[image]

I want to login to this webpage using selenium. I have tried selenium's find_element_by_ and used inspect element from browser. But I was not able to login. I was searching for ids,names, classnames so that I can pass data using send_keys but failed to do such stuff. Can anybody help me by providing some code which can push data to desired fields. Thanks.
This is what I have did till now.

```
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://paytm.com/')
driver.find_element_by_class_name('login').click()
```

After this I was trying to click button Log In using

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[contains(text(),'Log in')]").click()
```

but it failed. It gave error that it is not able to find 'Log in'. As by default Log in button is also clicked, I tried filling info in Email but then it gave error that it is not selected, first select the input field. I tried selecting the input field by clicking the button but nothing solved.I tried filling Mobile and password also but they also didn't worked.

**Edit**

Actually tags are also not working. I used names, classnames as well as ids but find_element_by_* is not working for this webpage

Comment: Please provide the error you got.

Comment: What does failed mean?

Comment: @Rahul I have updated the question statement.

Comment: Have you added time.sleep(5) after you click on the login button ?

Comment: Do you want to click the 'Secure Signin' button or the 'Log In' tab link?

Comment: A problem finding the tags via Selenium, or a problem even *knowing* what tag to look for?

Comment: @Prateek Firstly I want to click Log In button, then I want to fill info to Email and Password, then want to click secure login button.

Comment: @JohnGordon Both. Actually the tags I was using didn't helped.

Comment: If you don't even know what tags to look for, then I'm not sure how we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Login is in iframe, so you need to switch to Iframe first.

```
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://paytm.com/')
driver.find_element_by_class_name('login').click()

driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='md-dialog-container']//iframe"))
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
login = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "login")))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to *wait until the `Log In` link [becomes clickable](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits)*:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://paytm.com/')

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
login = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "login")))
login.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked Your screen, your login popup exists in an `iframe`. You need a context switch before you do anything on the popup.

```
driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@ng-hide='showVerificationScreen']"))
```

Don't forget to put appropriate waits for frame and contents to load AND switching back to default content using this:

```
driver.switch_to_default_content()
```